# I want to take my videos folder in my home folder and add locations to it from an external hdd on Ubuntu x64. Is it Possible?

Tags: directory

I can't seem to find a way to add locations to the folders located inside of my home folder. Why is that? And what do I need to do to accomplish this task, if it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes: I have the same thing: on my local HDD I have the videos I still have to watch, and on my NAS I have the videos I have already watched.  When I'm home, and the NAS is mounted I see them all, when on the road, I only see the ones on my local HDD.

**How to do this?**
Every time I move a Video directory to the NAS, I go to a terminal and do:

```
cd ~/Videos
md /media/user/Video_Archive/Summer_2014/
mv Summer2014/* /media/user/Video_Archive/Summer_2014/
rmdir Summer2014
ln --symbolic /media/user/Video_Archive/Summer_2014/
```

(actually I have a script called `av` (for Archive Video) that loops through the command-line parameters and moves them in one go, but you could also do the moves and create links with the file manager too)

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)